# error in c++ regarding boost and mac upgrade

Tags: c++

before upgrading my mac, everything works fine. After upgrade to Capitan, since openmpi becomes unusable (and I don't know why it seems only me is not able to use it in the world.) I have to switch to MPICH.

When try to compile the same program with boost mpi, serialization, etc. I got the error:

```
./common.h:67:23: error: expected expression
        ar & t.get<0>();
                      ^
```

Any help? Thank you.

Edit: t actually originates from serialization the complete code is as followed... It works in other clusters and my previous unungraded mac...

```
namespace boost { namespace serialization {


    template<typename Archive, typename T1>

    void serialize(Archive & ar,
                   boost::tuple<T1> & t,

                   const unsigned int)
    {
        ar & t.get<0>();
    }

    template<typename Archive, typename T1,typename T2>
    void serialize(Archive & ar,

                   boost::tuple<T1,T2> & t,

                   const unsigned int)
    {

        ar & t.get<0>();
        ar & t.get<1>();
    }


    template<typename Archive, typename T1,typename T2,typename T3>
    void serialize(Archive & ar,

                   boost::tuple<T1, T2, T3> & t,

                   const unsigned int)
    {

        ar & t.get<0>();
        ar & t.get<1>();
        ar & t.get<2>();
    }


    template<typename Archive, typename T1,typename T2,typename T3 ,typename T4>
    void serialize(Archive & ar,

                   boost::tuple<T1, T2, T3 ,T4> & t,

                   const unsigned int)
    {

        ar & t.get<0>();
        ar & t.get<1>();
        ar & t.get<2>();
        ar & t.get<3>();
    }

    template<typename Archive, typename T1,typename T2,typename T3 ,typename T4,typename T5>
    void serialize(Archive & ar,

                   boost::tuple<T1, T2, T3 ,T4, T5> & t,

                   const unsigned int)
    {

        ar & t.get<0>();
        ar & t.get<1>();
        ar & t.get<2>();
        ar & t.get<3>();
        ar & t.get<4>();
    }

    template<typename Archive, typename T1,typename T2,typename T3 ,typename T4,typename T5,typename T6 >
    void serialize(Archive & ar,

                   boost::tuple<T1, T2, T3 ,T4, T5, T6> & t,

                   const unsigned int)
    {

        ar & t.get<0>();
        ar & t.get<1>();
        ar & t.get<2>();
        ar & t.get<3>();
        ar & t.get<4>();
        ar & t.get<5>();
    }


    template<typename Archive, typename T1,typename T2,typename T3 ,typename T4,typename T5,typename T6 ,typename T7>
    void serialize(Archive & ar,

                   boost::tuple<T1, T2, T3 ,T4, T5, T6 ,T7> & t,

                   const unsigned int)
    {

        ar & t.get<0>();
        ar & t.get<1>();
        ar & t.get<2>();
        ar & t.get<3>();
        ar & t.get<4>();
        ar & t.get<5>();
        ar & t.get<6>();
    }


}}
```

Comment: Any idea what a `t` is? Really helpful if you do.

Comment: `t` has a dependent type, so you need `t.template get<0>()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I end up solving this with changing compiler back to gcc-4.8

just do

```
brew install gcc-4.8
```

And make the corresponding alias in ~/.bash_profile,

```
alias g++="g++-4.8"
alias gcc="gcc-4.8"

export PATH="/usr/local/sbin:$PATH"
export HOMEBREW_CC=gcc-4.8
export HOMEBREW_CXX=g++-4.8
```

afterwards, do:

```
brew install mpich --from_source
```